# Codeigniter validations are not showing anything

Tags: codeigniter, validation, model-view-controller

> This is my controller , where my form is submitting . I have created validations over here , but noting is working

```
public function add_masteradmin()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<div class='col-sm-5 col-form-label text-danger'>", '</div>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name','Full Name','required|alpha|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name','required|alpha|trim');
             if ($this->form_validation->run() == false ){
                 return redirect('Appconfig/master_admin');
             }
             else{
                 $post = $this->input->post();
                unset($post['submit']);

                $this->load->model('AppconfigModel');
                $this->AppconfigModel->insert_masteradmin($post);
                return redirect('Appconfig/master_admin');
             }
        }
```

> This is my view , Where my form is located. Currently, i am only validating my full_name

```
 <div class="col-md-10 mt-3 mb-4">
        <?php echo form_open('Appconfig/add_masteradmin', ['class'=>'form-inline form-color','id'=>'masterform']); ?>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
           <label  class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
             <div class="col-sm-7">
                 <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'full_name' , 'class'=>'form-control']);  ?>
              </div>
              <?php echo form_error('full_name'); ?>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
           <label  class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Username</label>
             <div class="col-sm-7">
                 <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'username' , 'class'=>'form-control']);  ?>
              </div>
           </div> 
  <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Submit','class'=>'btn btn-first d-block mx-auto mt-4', 'id'=>'sub'])   ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you don't need to `return` a redirect. Secondly, you can't directly access `validation_errors()` or `form_error()` if you are redirecting (as the validation errors only apply to the current submitted instance and not the one after redirect).

If you wish to get validation errors using a redirect **you have to assign them to a session variable** and retrieve that in your view after the redirect. **Or you can take the common approach that is described in the docs** and have the validation and processing all done in the same controller method.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller

Alternatively you can load the view instead of redirect however that approach modifies the url so that the user will be on `add_masteradmin` for all concurrent submissions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to a page, you should load the view you want to this is the smartest approach you can have in your case:

replace

```
return redirect('Appconfig/master_admin');
```

by

```
$this->load->view('AppConfig/master_admin');
```

Then you are not going to need to save the information in a session.